# Mule - how do you clear the payload/set the payload to null?

Tags: null, mule, mule-studio, payload

How do I clear the payload/set it to null in Mule? I've been using:

```
<set-payload value="" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

This works fine until I add an element to my flow using the GUI in Mule Studio, then the element changes to the following, which throws errors:

```
<set-payload  doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try setting it explicitly to null:

```
<set-payload value="#[null]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

Comment: This suggestion caused a null pointer exception for me. It is easier to just use a message enricher and return the payload opposed to this option.

Comment: null is different than empty.  This is not the best approach